# iPhoto opens with spinning beach ball and won't stop

Tags: photos.app

My daughter's MacBook Pro has a problem with iPhoto. Just get a spinning wheel after opening. I've tried deleting and reloading from time capsule backups when it did work. That didnt work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it attempting to do face recognition?

Comment: I don't think it is doing face recognition.

Comment: Is the spinning problem resolved? Can we do something else to help?

Answer (score 1):

Try holding the <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> key when launching iPhoto and rebuild your library.

Answer (score 0):

I advise that you try creating a new iPhoto library by following the instructions on [this Apple Support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2505).

Answer (score 0):

In case the above answers do not work or if you want to try something a little easier first, try moving the iPhoto plist file to the Desktop.

You can find it in `~/Library/Preferences`. It should have the name `com.apple.iPhoto.plist`. If you are running Lion, you will need to move the `com.apple.iPhoto.plist.lockfile` file as well. Try moving these to the Desktop and reopening the application. If that does not resolve the issue, put the `plist` files back and move on to the other suggestions.