# Mail account sync via iTunes not working

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, mail.app

I recently switched from Sparrow.app back to Mail.app and added a whole bunch of accounts. Now I am trying to sync them with my iPhone 5 via iTunes 11, since I am everything but keen on adding them manually in the iPhone settings.

But iTunes seems unable to find my accounts:

[image: Fetch]

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was an ordinary bug, it's working now (iTunes 11.0.2 + iOS 6.0.2)

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks so much for returning and explaining what was needed to resolve it.

Comment: I'm smelling sarcasm...

Comment: Actually no. As a moderator - I see hundreds of short answers that don't answer things as well as hundreds of abandoned questions where [you know the person](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36322/iphoto-opens-with-spinning-beach-ball-and-wont-stop) has found a fix and never returned to answer. No sarcasm - just appreciation for a small gesture on your part.